# How to solve AttributeNotSupportedException in Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

Everytime that we add a new attribute to items.xml, we have to execute a hybris update, otherwise we will get some error like: `JaloItemNotFoundException: no attribute Cart.newAttribute`

But, sometimes after executing an update, instead of getting JaloItemNotFoundException, we get something like:

```
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.AttributeNotSupportedException: cannot find attribute newAttribute
```

For this second case, it always work if we restart the server after the update. 
Is there any other way to fix that besides restarting the server after the update?

I worked for a company years ago that added this restart as a "deploy step"  after the update. I am trying to avoid that here.

I tried to execute several updates and clean type cache. But no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Platform Update with "Update Running System" is usually enough. If you have localization, impex, or some other changes, you might need to include the other options or extensions.

If you have a clustered environment, make sure all nodes have been updated / refreshed as well.

Make sure that your build and deploy process is something like:

- Build
- Deploy
- Restart Server. *You stop/start manually (or by script), or let Hybris restart itself when it detects changes from the deployment.*
- Run Platform Update

Answer (score 1):

**You can try to update the platform directly after the build from the command line(i.e "ant updatesystem") before starting the server.**

The restart after deploy is a pretty common step(In case the update system is performed with the server started).

I believe that one of the reasons the restart is needed is due to the fact that the Spring Context needs to be reinitialized since some of the beans need the new type system information.

For example, Let's say you need to create a new type and an interceptor for that newly created type. When deploying this change you do the following:

1. Change the binaries and start the server
2. Perform an update system in order for the database to get the latest columns and so on

Now if you try to see whether the interceptor is working you will see it does not work because when its spring bean was instantiated(during the server startup) the type that it is suppose to handle was not present in the database.

Because of that, after a restart the Interceptor works as expected.

**PS: The above described Interceptor problem might have been fixed somehow in the latest Hybris Versions.**